# Cannot GET /peerjs/peerjs/id

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, peerjs

In console it is outputting: peerjs.min.js:64 GET http://localhost:3030/peerjs/peerjs/id?ts=16144206488930.6577072628446186 404 (Not Found)

After expanding the error in the networks tab it showed: **Cannot GET /peerjs/id**

I tried changing the port number, even adding quotes at some places. I am trying to make a zoom clone. I am sure it's a tiny mistake which is causing such headache. So help would be appreciated.

**Client Side**

```js
    const socket = io('/');
    
    const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');
    
    const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
    myVideo.muted = true;
    
    var peer = new Peer(undefined, {
        path: '/peerjs',
        host: '/',
        port: '3030'
    });
    
    let myVideoStream
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
    }).then(stream => {
        myVideoStream = stream;
        addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);
    })
    
    peer.on('open', id => {
        socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id);
    })
    
    
    socket.on('user-connected', (userId) => {
        connecToNewUser(userId);
    })
    
    const connecToNewUser = (userId) => {
        console.log(userId);
    }
    
    const addVideoStream = (video, stream) => {
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
            video.play();
        })
        videoGrid.append(video)
    }
```

**Server Side**

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { ExpressPeerServer } = require('peer');
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
    debug: true
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    // res.status(200).send("Hello World")
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
    // res.send(`/${uuidv4()}`);
})

app.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
    res.render('room', { roomId: req.params.room });
})

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
        socket.join(roomId);
        socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId);
    })
})


server.listen(3030);
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a fix ? I am using vue.js 3

Comment: @NewBie1234 no I didn't find any fix, had to put the project on hold

Comment: anything new surfaced ?

Comment: The console says `/peerjs/peerjs/id` but the error says `/peerjs/id`...which one is true?  And once we straighten out which URL is the right one...then which route do you want to have handle that request?

Comment: If anyone is else is facing the issue, as mentioned in the answer "app.use(/peerjs, peerServer)" should to added and also with respect to the above question on the client side peer-object "path" is defined but while starting peer-server "path" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Just add `app.use('/peerjs', peerServer)` on your server-side then you will be fine.

Comment: @Piyush add this line "app.use('/peerjs', peerServer)" that is the only missing point.

Answer (score 0):

had same issue found the solution by adding

```
const peerServer = ExpressPeerServer(server, {
   debug: true,
   key:"add-some-key"      <--- this fixed it add some key
});

app.use('/peerjs', peerServer)
```

then access via

```
http://localhost:9000/peerjs/add-some-key/id
```

should give a key